# How to add gif image in the background of view pager android studio?

Tags: android

Currently, I'm doing mobile onboarding in the android studio. I already finish creating view pager and slider. Is there a way to add a gif image on the background view pager. I try to add a gif image on the view pager, but this gif image covers all my contents in the slider. Need some advice on this matter

viewpager.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gif_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/onboarding_paperplane_blue" />

    <Button
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/buttonGetStart"
        style="@style/Font_Button_onboarding"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="134dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="134dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:onClick="startLoginActivity"
        android:text="Start Now"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="485dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/dotLayout"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just move gif image below viewpager like this. But I think you should put all your content to custom view and use ConstraintLayout replace for RelativeLayout.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/gif_ImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/onboarding_paperplane_blue" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:id="@+id/buttonGetStart"
            style="@style/Font_Button_onboarding"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="134dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="134dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
            android:onClick="startLoginActivity"
            android:text="Start Now"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="485dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dotLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/dotLayout"
            android:alpha=".5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, it didn`t work out, the gif background not showing

Comment: because your Viewpager match_parent width and height, can not see anything below.

Comment: If you want to add as a background of view pager then add the gif on the fragment which is being used in your view pager